# Dropbox in stealth mode

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have not tried anything since I don't know from where to start. How can I implement code so that I don't get anything which shows that dropbox is syncing or updating. In other words, I want to create an application which works stealthly and automatically updates dropbox without the user even noticing anything?

Comment: Sounds like a noobish try to collect data from a keylogger. So why would you want to do that?

Comment: Trying to play with dropbox api and I wanted to create my own monitoring tool for my kids...and as always using python for fun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can change this yourself(unless there's an api avail for it) but the settings for notifications is in the dropbox preferences.  I believe the user would have to go there and turn it off globally since any change within dropbox will be reported to the end user based on the global preference settings.

I'm not sure if you can disable the dropbox icon from changing while updating but you maybe able to do something to growl(how it displays) changes. Not sure but worth a look in your case.